Next14 project deployed in Vercel with "notfound" page infinitely reloading
This happens only in production. What can it be?
The only import I have in the notfound page is:
import Link from "next/link";

And this is my nextconfig file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
     },
};

export default nextConfig;


I've already looked up answers here on StackOverFlow, but they just say that this only happens when it's not in production.
